# Store checkbox selected into a textarea

Tags: channel-form

I am trying to store items selected from a list of checkbox shown in the template, into a textarea custom field(item), but like this seems not working, and I am getting this error:Error Number: 1054
Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'
Any idea if I can achieve this?

{exp:channel:form channel="my_channel" entry_id="{segment_3}" limit="1" preserve_checkboxes="yes"}

```
<div id="scroll" style="overflow-y:scroll; height: 80px;border:1px solid #ccc;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="item1"{checked} />item1<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="item2"{checked} />item2 <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="item3"{checked} />item3 <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="item4"{checked} />item4 <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="item5"{checked} />item5
    </div>
```

{/exp:channel:form}

Comment: Still wondering about this ... any thoughts?